# How to customize pynotify?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pynotify

1. How to set icon size in the notifications?
2. How to set how much time the notification have to be shown?
3. Where is a complete pynotify documentation?
4. Can the notification be clickable? (example: if I click on the notification, print "hello world" in the terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set how much time the
>   notification have to be shown?

Ubuntu uses Notify OSD, which [does not allow you to control the timeout](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines#Avoiding%20non-expiring%20notifications). The timeout duration depends on the length of the message.

> Where is a complete pynotify
>   documentation?

On Ubuntu, `pynotify` is provided by the `python-notify` package.
According to /usr/share/doc/python-notify/copyright, the package contents come from [the galago-project](http://www.galago-project.org/files/releases/source/notify-python/).

The latest tarball was on 2006-10-08, and contains no documentation.

The closest thing I could find to documentation was the "[Desktop Notification Specification](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/index.html)".

> Can the notification be clickable?
>   (example: if I click on the
>   notification, print "hello world" in
>   the terminal).

Unfortunately, no. See "[Avoiding actions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines#Avoiding%20actions)".